# Порекомендуйте книги по Javascript

Tags: javascript

Привет, всем! Мне понравилось это сообщество и отзывчивость местных обитателей. Я хочу внести свой вклад, помогая новичкам и всем людям, творя полезные проекты, но у меня весьма поверхностные знания по веб программированию в целом.

Мне интересен Javascript, но я не прочь учить и другие технологии. Понимаю, вопрос глупый по сути, но некоторые книги для меня сложны, некоторые говорят о том, что я уже знаю или в них пишутся морально устаревшие приёмы разработки.

Я усердный и готов к обучению, чтобы уметь творить и помогать тем, кто нуждается в наставлении на верный путь.

Благодарю всех кто прочёл, заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Сейчас ты по полной отхватишь отзывчивости :D

Comment: @Khipster, я осознанно пошёл на этот поступок. Найти курсы по искомой теме я не смог в своей стране, так что, мне придётся искать знания другим путём. К наказанию готов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне очень нравится ресурс Ильи Кантора [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/). Там довольно просто и подробно объясняются все самые важные аспекты. А вообще практика - самый лучший учебник.